# Edge cookies transfer

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm wanting to transfer cookie files from one win11 machine to another with Edge browser. I copied the cookie folder from one machine to another which is located in AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network folder.

When I try to go to a website on second machine that I've logged in with the first machine the website asks for my login data as if there are no cookies transferred. What could be the issue here?

Comment: You likely need to copy whole profile, due to encryption, which may differ. If you need to, change password afterwards.